# omnetpp ,PREXT,and vehicle transmission range

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Eavesdropper/RSU is receiving the Beacons messages from the vehicle which is outside. How to fix this such that a given Eavesdropper/RSU receives the data only from the vehicles which are within 300 m of range of eavesdropper/RSU

Answer (score 1):

I advise you to take a look on this link:

[Change the transmission signal strength for a specific set of vehicles during the run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172247/change-the-transmission-signal-strength-for-a-specific-set-of-vehicles-during-th)

I think you were tricked by the graphical representation as these message receptions are not necessarily happening (apart of them are candidate only, so it is just a check)